# Getting PySide Hello App to run under Canopy

Tags: python, pyside, canopy

A Canopy user here learning about PySide.  When I run the demo code below, QApplication complains the event loop is already running.'

```
import sys
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *


# Create a Qt application
#app = QApplication(sys.argv) #QApplication complains an instance already exists
app = QApplication.instance() #So we just ask for the instance.

#app.aboutToQuit.connect(app.deleteLater)
# Create a Label and show it
label = QLabel("Hello World")
label.show()
# Enter Qt application main loop
app.exec_()
sys.exit()
```

So how can I get this simple code to run?

Comment: It could be running in a separate process. I would try rebooting my computer and seeing if the error still happens.

Comment: OK, I did a restart, but same problem.  QApplication complains the event loop is already running.

Comment: I disabled Canopy's use of PyLab in Canopy preferences and the code runs now.  I hate to give up PyLab in Canopy though.  There must be a way around this.

Comment: Never used Canopy or PyLab, but there must be a `QApplication` already created which has had its event loop started before your script runs. So just comment out the `app.exec_()` line (and don't try to create your own `QApplication`). (PS: A little websearching reveals that PyLab can be run in `inline` mode, as opposed to `qt` mode, but I have no idea how/if that can be changed within Canopy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Pylab is a mode of IPython which starts an event loop for the IPython front end so that you can interact at the IPython command line with your GUI.

Here's an simple example of code which will run with or without Pylab.

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui
app = QtGui.QApplication.instance()
standalone = app is None
if standalone:
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
wid = QtGui.QWidget()
wid.resize(250,150)
wid.setWindowTitle('Simple')
wid.show()
if standalone:
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
else:
    print "We're back with the Qt window still active"
```

Comment: For the record, added this to Canopy Knowledge Base: https://support.enthought.com/entries/64158730-Running-a-Qt-program-from-the-Canopy-GUI